# Can i use Route::get('/') normally on Laravel?

Tags: php, laravel, routes

I have a Laravel 8 project. Everything work fine except  the code below

```
Route::get('/', function ()
{
    return redirect('/login');
});
```

Those code only run when i clear the route cache with `php artisan route:clear` or it will return this error everytime after i cache route:

```
Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\Exception\MethodNotAllowedHttpException
The GET method is not supported for this route. Supported methods: HEAD.
```

I want my users can go to login page despite of they access the `http://localhost/myproject/public/` or `http://localhost/myproject/public/login`

If anyone have the answer, pleas help me. Thank you!
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/urt7y.png)

Comment: `public` should not be in the path. What webserver are you using? Could you try running the project with `php artisan serve`

Comment: im using xampp on local for my dev version and apache2 on vps for my production version. i use alias directory for my project so instead of myporject/public/login it will be myproject/login. But the issue still the same, just a little diff that is no public in the path.

Comment: i tried 'php artisan serve', still get the same problem

Comment: in what part of the project are you running `php artisan serve`?

Comment: sorry i dont understand your question. i run `php artisn serve` on "myproject" directory

Comment: For routes whose contain segment same with folder name, you must handle in `.htaccess` file (Apache) or `nginx.conf` (Nginx), of course if you're using virtual host.

Comment: Thank you. I will note that

Answer (score 0):

1.Add this at the top of your web.php `use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Route;`

2.

```
Route::get('/greeting', function () {
    return 'Hello World';
});
```

[Routing Laravel](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/routing)

Comment: And if the route only have slash, will it work normally, Example `Route::get('/', function () { return 'Hello World'; });`